# Remmina returning credentials error for Win 10

Tags: rdp, remmina

I am attempting to remote to my Windows 10 machine from an Ubuntu 18.04 machine via remmina. I am entering the external IP, and my Microsoft account credentials. It thinks for a moment and returns an error asking me to check my username and password. I changed my password just to if that reset everything. No luck. I am thoroughly confused, I've followed every guide to the letter and while theirs works mine continues to fail.

Comment: You might want to specify, is the Windows host on your local network, or on a network on the Internet ? If local network, try its internal IP. If over Internet (and so you must use the external IP), you would need to confirm that the firewall lets the connections through appropriately - sometimes errors are misdescribed. Remember also, it is the account for the Windows instance you need, not "Microsoft account" (which implies the account used on microsoft.com sites)